Comparison of macros fails
I am new to LaTex and have been given a problem by my colleagues. They define a document type in a TeX file (e.g. 'svvr', 'srs', ...). This external definition corresponds to lines 4 and 5 in my example code.
Now I should use this external definition in my TeX file to decide which document-dependent processing should take place. To do this, I have written an MWE to test the selection.
My test code originally comes from the Internet and compares the job name with a given string (e.g. "{\detokenize{svvr}"). I named my TeX file "svvr.tex" to be able to make the comparison with the job name.
My problem now is that when I compare with the job name (MWE 1), the selection works correctly.
\documentclass{article}

% Own TeX file:
\begin{document}
    \edef\docTypeExt{\jobname}
    % Specify which document type is to be handled: 'svvr', 'srs', ...
    \edef\docTypeSvvr{\detokenize{svvr}} 
    \edef\docTypeSrs{\detokenize{srs}}

    \textbf{\jobname} 
    \textbf{\docShortcut}
    \textbf{\docTypeSvvr}
    \textbf{\docTypeSrs}
    \newline
    
    \ifx\docTypeExt\docTypeSvvr
        true
    \else
        false: \\
        \jobname \\
        \docShortcut \\
        \docTypeSvvr
    \fi
\newline

    \ifx\docTypeExt\docTypeSrs
        true
    \else
        false: \\
        \jobname \\
        \docShortcut \\
        \docTypeSrs
    \fi

\end{document}

But if I compare to the external definition by my colleagues (MWE 2), the comparison fails.
\documentclass{article}

% Given code, defined in included TeX file: 'svvr', 'srs', ...
\newcommand { \docpropPTdocShortcut } {svvr}    % Define document type here!
\gdef\docShortcut{\docpropPTdocShortcut}

% Own TeX file:
\begin{document}
    \edef\docTypeExt{\docShortcut}
    % Specify which document type is to be handled: 'svvr', 'srs', ...
    \edef\docTypeSvvr{\detokenize{svvr}} 
    \edef\docTypeSrs{\detokenize{srs}}

    \textbf{\jobname} 
    \textbf{\docShortcut}
    \textbf{\docTypeSvvr}
    \textbf{\docTypeSrs}
    \newline
    
    \ifx\docTypeExt\docTypeSvvr
        true
    \else
        false: \\
        \jobname \\
        \docShortcut \\
        \docTypeSvvr
    \fi
\newline

    \ifx\docTypeExt\docTypeSrs
        true
    \else
        false: \\
        \jobname \\
        \docShortcut \\
        \docTypeSrs
    \fi

\end{document}

How must the selection be structured so that it also works with the external definition?
I have modified the definitions, but all attempts so far have failed.

This belongs to anothe SE community, namely https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Thanks for your information. I moved my question to tex.stackexchange.com
